# How to add Gson extras to an Android project?

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gson

I am using gson parser (latest version -> 2.8.2).

I would like to use [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) which is part of the gson extras.

In my `build.gradle` there is currently a single compile directive:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

However this gives me only the gson lib without the extras (RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory is not recognized in the project...).

I have looked at gson extras' pom file (https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/pom.xml) and 
tried to add below line to my build gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson-extras:2.8.2'
```

But gradle just won't compile the gson extras:

```
"Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson-extras:2.8.2"
```

Any Idea how to make this work?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.gson:gson-extras:2.8.2

The extra **package is not published** in Maven.

You can check these issues:

- https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1104
- https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1123

As you can read this package is not published and the best way to use the classes inside is just to include source-code in your project.

Comment: For clarity - what does including source code means? Does it mean that I can just copy paste the code with License header into a file and directly use it or something else?

Comment: There is a third-party released maven package available at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.danilopianini/gson-extras/0.2.1

Answer (score 5):

As mention in the maven page
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson-extras/2.8.5!

you need to use the specified maven repo

> Note: this artifact it located at CronApp repository
>   (https://artifactory.cronapp.io/public-release/)

in gradle you can add custom repositories that way:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://artifactory.cronapp.io/public-release/" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually maintaining a build of the vanilla gson-extras and publishing it in Maven Central.
You can find it at: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.danilopianini/gson-extras/

include it in Gradle by

```
implementation("org.danilopianini:gson-extras:0.2.1")
```