# How to add gson extra code

Tags: java, gson

'I have to  use  https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java in one of my project for deserialization and it's working perfectly for my case.

In this post https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1104 I could read it as  "You should include source-code."
 (similarly here also  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson)

Could some one please clarify what it does really mean? 
Does it mean that I can just copy paste the code with License header into a file and directly use it ?

I posted the query in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/odQWZShvY-8 and I did not get a response. May be it's very silly question, that's why no one responding. But It will be really helpful if someone can clarify my doubt.

There is also a similar [How to Add Gson Extras to Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001264/how-to-add-gson-extras-to-android-project) question but here also I did not fully understand what "You should include source-code." means. I'm too afraid to run into a license issue.