# Gson deserialize base class for a generic type adapter

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following class:

```
public class Kit {
    private String name;
    private int num;
}
```

And I have a class which extends Kit with additional functionality:

```
public class ExtendedKit extends Kit {
    private String extraProperty;
}
```

With Gson, I want to be able to deserialize both of these classes, and more of different types, without creating a bunch of type adapters for them, as they all have the same Json structure:

```
{
    "type": "com.driima.test.ExtendedKit",
    "properties": {
        "name": "An Extended Kit",
        "num": 124,
        "extra_property": "An extra property"
    }
}
```

Which is passed into the following type adapter registered to my GsonBuilder:

```
public class GenericAdapter<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {
    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String classType = object.get("type").getAsString();
        JsonElement element = object.get("properties");

        try {
            return context.deserialize(element, Class.forName(classType));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Unknown element type: " + type, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thing is, that works for `ExtendedKit`, but it doesn't work if I want to deserialize just a `Kit`, without the extraProperty, as it calls causes a NullPointerException when it tries to call context.deserialize() on the properties object. Is there any way I can get around this?

---

Here is my code for the GsonBuilder I'm using:

```
private static final GsonBuilder GSON_BUILDER = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new PostProcessExecutor())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Kit.class, new GenericAdapter<Kit>());
```

Note: PostProcessExecutor is added so that I can apply post-processing to any object I deserialize that can be post-processed. There's an article [here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/post-processing-on-gson-deserialization-26ce5790137d) which aided me with implementing that feature.

Comment: Does this _but it doesn't work if I want to de-serialize just a `Kit` without the extraProperty_ mean that you give Json without extra property AND having `"type": "com.driima.test.Kit"`?

Comment: Yes. This is correct. Sorry for not clearing that up in my question. I am using that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `JsonDeserializer` is a good choice here:

- You need either bind each type to the `Gson` instance in `GsonBuilder` that's a kind of error-prone, or use `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`.
- For the latter you'd run into infinite recursion (if I'm not wrong: because the context only provides a mechanism to deserialize an instance of the *same* type).

The following type adapter factory can overcome the above limitations:

```java
final class PolymorphicTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // Let's not hard-code `Kit.class` here and let a user pick up types at a call-site
    private final Predicate<? super Class<?>> predicate;

    private PolymorphicTypeAdapterFactory(final Predicate<? super Class<?>> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory get(final Predicate<? super Class<?>> predicate) {
        return new PolymorphicTypeAdapterFactory(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final Class<? super T> rawClass = typeToken.getRawType();
        if ( !predicate.test(rawClass) ) {
            // Something we cannot handle? Try pick the next best type adapter factory
            return null;
        }
        // This is what JsonDeserializer fails at:
        final TypeAdapter<T> writeTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        // Despite it's possible to use the above type adapter for both read and write, what if the `type` property points to another class?
        final Function<? super Class<T>, ? extends TypeAdapter<T>> readTypeAdapterResolver = actualRawClass -> {
            if ( !rawClass.isAssignableFrom(actualRawClass) ) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot parse as " + actualRawClass);
            }
            return gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.get(actualRawClass));
        };
        return PolymorphicTypeAdapter.get(rawClass, writeTypeAdapter, readTypeAdapterResolver);
    }

    private static final class PolymorphicTypeAdapter<T>
            extends TypeAdapter<T> {

        private final Class<? super T> rawClass;
        private final TypeAdapter<T> writeTypeAdapter;
        private final Function<? super Class<T>, ? extends TypeAdapter<T>> readTypeAdapterResolver;

        private PolymorphicTypeAdapter(final Class<? super T> rawClass, final TypeAdapter<T> writeTypeAdapter,
                final Function<? super Class<T>, ? extends TypeAdapter<T>> readTypeAdapterResolver) {
            this.rawClass = rawClass;
            this.writeTypeAdapter = writeTypeAdapter;
            this.readTypeAdapterResolver = readTypeAdapterResolver;
        }

        // Since constructors are meant only to assign parameters to fields, encapsulate the null-safety handling in the factory method
        private static <T> TypeAdapter<T> get(final Class<? super T> rawClass, final TypeAdapter<T> writeTypeAdapter,
                final Function<? super Class<T>, ? extends TypeAdapter<T>> readTypeAdapterResolver) {
            return new PolymorphicTypeAdapter<>(rawClass, writeTypeAdapter, readTypeAdapterResolver)
                    .nullSafe();
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final T value)
                throws IOException {
            jsonWriter.beginObject();
            jsonWriter.name("type");
            jsonWriter.value(rawClass.getName());
            jsonWriter.name("properties");
            writeTypeAdapter.write(jsonWriter, value);
            jsonWriter.endObject();
        }

        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader jsonReader)
                throws IOException {
            jsonReader.beginObject();
            // For simplicity's sake, let's assume that the class property `type` always precedes the `properties` property
            final Class<? super T> actualRawClass = readActualRawClass(jsonReader);
            final T value = readValue(jsonReader, actualRawClass);
            jsonReader.endObject();
            return value;
        }

        private Class<? super T> readActualRawClass(final JsonReader jsonReader)
                throws IOException {
            try {
                requireProperty(jsonReader, "type");
                final String value = jsonReader.nextString();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final Class<? super T> actualRawClass = (Class<? super T>) Class.forName(value);
                return actualRawClass;
            } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
                throw new AssertionError(ex);
            }
        }

        private T readValue(final JsonReader jsonReader, final Class<? super T> rawClass)
                throws IOException {
            requireProperty(jsonReader, "properties");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final Class<T> castRawClass = (Class<T>) rawClass;
            final TypeAdapter<T> readTypeAdapter = readTypeAdapterResolver.apply(castRawClass);
            return readTypeAdapter.read(jsonReader);
        }

        private static void requireProperty(final JsonReader jsonReader, final String propertyName)
                throws IOException {
            final String name = jsonReader.nextName();
            if ( !name.equals(propertyName) ) {
                throw new JsonParseException("Unexpected property: " + name);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

An example of use that's specific for your `Kit` class only (the method reference below just checks if `Kit` is a super-class of the given actual raw class or the latter is `Kit` itself):

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(PolymorphicTypeAdapterFactory.get(Kit.class::isAssignableFrom))
        .create();
```

Note that your problem is not unique, and your case is almost covered with [`RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java), but `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` does not segregate `type` and `properties` as your example does.

**P.S.** Note that this type adapter factory is far way from being truly generic: it does not work with *types* (classes are a particular case of types), *generic* types, etc. In case of interest, but not over-engineering of course, you might like to reference my solution for encoding types with their parameterization either using `Type` instances [object serialization mechanism](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605380) (too cryptic and tightly bound to a specific platform) or using types and generic types notation [parsing using JParsec](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605388) (both links refer the Russian-speaking StackExchange site).

Comment: This is great. This does exactly what I want and I can still use my PostProcessExecutor. There is one small problem I am trying to fix though. I have two kinds of Post processing - the first kind just post-processes using an empty postProcess() method. This is fine if I don't need any additional information, but in some cases, there is data in my json which I do not want to temporarily store, and want to evaluate, so I have another postProcess method which passes along the "properties" object from the json. Is there a way I can get the same functionality? `postProcess(JsonObject properties);`

Comment: Never mind - I just created an additional Type Adapter Factory that can handle this. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: I see some issues while deserializing the produced json to the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one problem in your adapter is that it actually is never called for `ExtendedKit` only for `Kit`. So that is why it *works* with `ExtendedKit`,  I guess. Gson can not handle generics by default anyway because of type erasure.

Be that as it may: it is a good and clear practice to declare the object that is to be deserialized just as the Json presents since it usually reduces the coding of the logic for adapters etc...

I suggest that you declare a wrapper class for `Kit` like:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KitWrapper {
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("properties") // 
    private Kit kit;
}
```

This is easier to deserialize with `TypeAdapter` like:

```
@Slf4j
public class KitWrapperAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<KitWrapper>  {
    @Override
    public KitWrapper deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                   JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Class<? extends Kit> classKit =
                    (Class<? extends Kit>)Class.forName(json.getAsJsonObject()
                         .get("type").getAsString() );
            JsonElement jeProperties = json.getAsJsonObject().get("properties");
            Kit kit = context.deserialize(jeProperties, classKit);
            // Not needed to parse anymore, new KitWrapper can be created
            // with this information
            return new KitWrapper(classKit.getName(), kit);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("{}", e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So register this adapter and get Kit by:

```
Kit kit = kitWrapper.getKit();
```

As **Lyubomyr Shaydariv** in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49045658/6413377) mentioned your case is *almost suitable* for `RunTimeAdapterFactory`. It just seems that the `type` should be a property of the deserialized object, not so that it is *top-level* property and the actual object as lower level. In other words, if you can change your Json & `Kit` accordingly to:

```
{
    "type": "com.driima.test.ExtendedKit",
    "name": "An Extended Kit",
    "num": 124,
    "extra_property": "An extra property"
}
```

it might work fine. In that case you might be interested of [How to add Gson extras to an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47001264/6413377) (even not Maven or Gradle user).

But if can not then i suggest that wrapper class.

However, as you can see it is not so big deal to code by yourself either.