# Deserializing nested / recursive JSON into Java objects with inheritance

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, json-deserialization

I have a json which is complex/nested. My json file consists of two equivalent java objects. One is `Complex_Expression` and another is `Simple_Expression`. 
`Complex_Expression` is in the following form:

```
{
    "SomeOpearator":0,
    "ASpecificKey":1, //the value 1 is fixed for complex expression.
    "Expressions":[ ] //array of one or more expressions
}
```

`Simple Expression` is in the following form:

```
{
    "Operand":"Some String Value",
    "ASpecificKey":0, //the value 0 is fixed for simple expressions.
    "SomeComparisionOpearator":1, // enums which associates int to different comparison operators.
    "Value":["String1"] //this is an array of strings.
}
```

The `Expressions` in turn can have `Complex_Expression` and/or `Simple_Expression`. The json file always starts from `Complex_Expression`. I have to deserialize this JSON file. My final goal is to make an expression using`Complex_Expression` and `Simple_Expression` objects and with some logics in these classes. I don't mind using `jackson` or `gson` or maybe other dependencies.

Till now I have created a base class called `Expression`. `Complex_Expression` and `Simple_Expression` both inherits this class. Then I started writing `Custom Json Deserializer`. But in the custom deserializer I am stuck and I don't know how should I proceed. Please help me on this. My `Simple_Expression` class looks like this and somewhat similar is the `Complex_Expression` class.

```
public class Simple_Expression extends Expression
{
    @JsonProperty("Operand") //use jackson deserializer for this class.
    public String Operand;

    @JsonProperty("SomeComparisionOpearator")
    public SomeComparisionOpearator someCompareOperator;

    @JsonProperty("Value")
    public Object value;

    public Simple_Expression()
    {
        super(ASpecificKey.Simple); //Simple corresponds to 0
    }
}
```

**Update**

Some more description about my input and output. With input given a JSON string like this:

```
{
  "SomeOpearator": 0,
  "ASpecificKey": 1,
  "Expressions": [
    {
      "SomeOpearator": 1,
      "ASpecificKey": 1,
      "Expressions": [
        {
          "Operand": "People",
          "ASpecificKey": 0,
          "SomeComparisionOpearator": 14,
          "Value": [
            "Rich"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "SomeOpearator": 1,
      "ASpecificKey": 1,
      "Expressions": [
        {
          "Operand": "Grade",
          "ASpecificKey": 0,
          "SomeComparisionOpearator": 2,
          "Value": [
            "Grade A"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I should be able to do something like this, assuming jackson deserializer:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Expression myExpressionObject = mapper.convertValue(jsonString, Expression.class);
```

It should give me the deserialized object into the myExpressionObject which will consists of a list of expressions (Arraylist or Array, no problem).

Comment: You should share your java code and example of expected input/output data of the serialization/deserialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easy with Gson extras [`RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) because you have the field `ASpecificKey` that can be used as type discriminator. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47001576/6413377) for usage. You can just copy the source to your project if you already have Gson included.

I took a liberty to fix your Java naming convention so classes actually look like (and also your JSON should be fixed to correct convention):

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Expression {
    private int aSpecificKey;
}

@Getter @Setter
public class SimpleExpression extends Expression {
    public SimpleExpression() {
        setASpecificKey(0);
    }
    private String operand;
    private int someComparisonOperator;
    private String[] values; 
}

@Getter @Setter
public class ComplexExpression extends Expression {
    public ComplexExpression() {
        setASpecificKey(1);
    }   
    private String someOperator;
    private Expression[] expressions;
}
```

Against this kind of DTOs you could just instantiate  a specific `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`:

```
final RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Expression> expressionTypeFactory = 
    RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory               
        .of(Expression.class, "aSpecificKey")
        .registerSubtype(SimpleExpression.class, "0")
        .registerSubtype(ComplexExpression.class, "1")
```

Then deserializing would be like:

```
Expression e = getGson(expressionTypeFactory)
        .fromJson(getPackageResourceReader(YOUR_NOTATION_FIXED_JSON),
                                               Expression.class);
```

Note that Gson will not by default deserialize the type discriminator `aSpecificKey` that is why there is default constructors that set that. If you do not need it you can remove the default constructors.

Comment: My `someComparisonOperator` and `somOperator` keys  are actually enums like` Equals,NotEquals...` . When I am deserializing using this. Those fields are automatically assigned null.  Do I need to make changes the enum classes as well?

Comment: @SunilKumar Add your enum class to the question and at least one model class how yo  use it, like `private EnumOperator someComparisonOperator`?. Also you can take alook at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8211304/6413377).

Comment: Never mind. With the help of above link I did it. Thanks!!